# Persistent: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class)"

Tags: eclipse, java-8, tomcat7

I'm struggling with this the whole day now. I created a Web App on my Mac using Eclipse Neon EE. My JRE is Oracle Java SE 8 [1.8.0_111]. When I deploy my Web-App to apache-tomcat-7.0.72 on my local machine everything is working fine. My target machine is however a VM running Debian Debian 8.6 Jessie. Initially I copied the whole Tomcat Directory over to the VM and started Tomcat there. I can run everything on the remote Tomcat machine, except my own Web App. I got a runtime Exception: "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class MyServlet)"

I made sure I have the same Java version running on the Debian Machine. I do however get the same Exception.

I downloaded Eclipse on the target machine, copied over the Source files, recompiled everything and deployed the WebApp again to the Tomcat Server.

To my big surprise I got the same Exception again! This shouldn't be possible.

The weird thing is that I'm able to run the code as Java Program fine and my Junit Tests are also indicating everything is working fine.

Here's the output of the command 'java -version on both the Mac and the VM:

```
Evert-Jans-MacBook-Pro:~ root# java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
Evert-Jans-MacBook-Pro:~ root# ssh vm1

root@vm1's password: 
Welcome to Wordpress, TurnKey GNU/Linux 14.1 / Debian 8.6 Jessie

  System information (as of Sun Oct 30 22:08:15 2016)

    System load:  0.02               Memory usage:  18%
    Processes:    132                Swap usage:    0%
    Usage of /:   38.5% of 16.61GB   IP address for eth0:
    192.168.0.25

Last login: Sun Oct 30 21:36:26 2016 from 192.168.0.11
root@vm1 ~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
root@wordpress ~#
```

I'm stuck. Please help. The full StackTrace is below:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tk/evertwagenaar/lucene/servlet/LingoServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class tk.evertwagenaar.lucene.servlet.LingoServlet)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3200)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Should I download a Separate Tomcat Server? (Like Tomcat 8) Or use WebSphere?

I'll try tomorrow. This gave me a terrible headache for now. Time to take some rest.

Comment: Tomcat is running an older JRE. Check the startup script to find out which java version it's using.

Comment: No. Same JRE. I know because there's only one JRE installed on both machines.

Comment: The log output says otherwise.

Comment: Not only the JVM/JRE, but also every tool performing byte code manipulation (like resource injection or compiling additional dependent classes), have to support this class version. I think, upgrading Tomcat and its libraries is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Class file version 52 represents classes built for Java 8. The error means that that classes built for Java 8 are not supported by your runtime. While your default JRE is 1.8.x it doesn't mean your Tomcat installation runs with the same JRE. You can check the full command line of your tomcat process with the following command, assuming your tomcat runs on port 8080:

```
sudo lsof -Fp -i :8080 \
  | awk 'match($0, /p([0-9]+)/, a){ print a[1] }' \
  | xargs ps -wwo command -p
```

That would probably indicate what JRE version Tomcat is using.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: lsof doesn't work. I used Webmin to search for the task running port 8080. Both machines used java-8-oracle. I fixed the problem by (re)importing servlet-api.jar from Tomcat's lib folder. There's still an issue with my servlet. It's caching stuff from earlier sessions but my main problem is fixed. Thanks.